# Can you help me provide some examples of 3-co-SAT?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, turing-machines, np, co-np

Recently I'm studying 3SAT problem, which is a NP-complete problem. I feel that it's easy to find a boolean formula which is satisfiable,but how about boolean formulas which are unsatisfiable， namely 3-co-SAT problem.
Can you help me provide some examples of 3-co-SAT?

The definition of 3SAT problem is supplemented here, which is quoted from the book Computational Theory.

> 3SAT = {$<\phi>|\phi$ is a satisfiable 3cnf-formula}

Then the definition of 3-co-SAT is

> 3-co-SAT = {$<\phi>|\phi$ is an unsatisfiable 3cnf-formula}

Is there any problem about the definition of the above sat, 3-co-sat problem?

Can you help me provide some examples of 3-co-SAT?

Comment: Take a random 3CNF with enough clauses, say five times the number of variables.

Answer (score 1):

The formula
$$(x\vee y \vee z) \wedge (\overline{x}\vee y \vee z) \wedge(x\vee \overline{y} \vee z) \wedge(x\vee y \vee \overline{z}) \wedge(\overline{x}\vee \overline{y} \vee z) \wedge(\overline{x}\vee y \vee \overline{z}) \wedge(x\vee \overline{y} \vee \overline{z}) \wedge(\overline{x}\vee \overline{y} \vee \overline{z})$$
is in $3$-co-SAT.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's easy to find that the formula of 3 variables. And how about 1 variables, 2 variables, 4 variables, 5 variables,...?

Comment: For 1 variable, you could choose $(x\vee x \vee x) \wedge (\overline{x}\vee\overline{x}\vee \overline{x})$. A good way to find an unsatisfiable formula is to use a truth table.

Comment: I reviewed this question, can you give me some examples of 4 variables, 5 variables? I tried to find it, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pick any unsatisfiable CNF SAT instance.
2. Transform the CNF to 3-SAT.
3. The new instance is an element of 3-co-SAT.

Any unsatisfiable satisfiability instance undergoing the same 3-SAT CNF transformation is an example of 3-co-SAT.